# Read URL/Google Docs / XML in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have Google Spreadsheet, it update data every few minutes

I have it published as a html page

I want to import that from that html page to phonegap

google doc support Android XML as well.

how can I read text from html into phonegap which supports html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IIRC you can get Google Docs spreadsheets as JSON fairly easily.

This is the only link I could find in my bookmarks for it, but it should get you started: http://david-burger.blogspot.com.au/2009/03/display-google-docs-spreadsheet-data-on.html